# How to add a field to a group with form_alter

Tags: 7, entities

I have a group in a node set as a vertical tab, and I want to add some markup into this vertical tab via code. How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: What are the steps you did for this ? Any approch you follow?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you are doing this in a module named **custom**.

First, take a look at how the form is structured using **dsm($form)** in custom.module.  Make sure you have the devel module enabled and that you have permissions to see devel's output.

```
<?php

custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  dsm($form);
}
```

That will give you the structure of the **$form** array, which you can then add your markup to.  So, let's say that you want to add some markup to the author pane in the vertical tabs.  From the output from **dsm($form)**, we see that we are working with **$form['author']**.

So, in **custom_form_alter()**, we simply add the markup element we desire using the standards documented in the [Drupal 7 Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7).

In the code below, I also give the custom element (which I have aptly named "custom") a weight, so it appears above the other elements.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function custom_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  // Add custom markup to the "Authoring Information" tab when adding or editing a page.
  if ($form_id == 'page_node_form') {
    $form['author']['custom']['#markup'] = 'Text goes here';
    $form['author']['custom']['#weight'] = -9;
  }
}
```

Also, rather than using an if statement to target the form id, I could have used **hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()**, like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function custom_form_page_node_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  // Add custom markup to the "Authoring Information" tab when adding or editing a page.
  $form['author']['custom']['#markup'] = 'Text goes here';
  $form['author']['custom']['#weight'] = -9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found a solution:

```
$form['markup'] = array(
  '#markup' => '<div>markup</div>',
);
$form['#group_children']['markup'] = 'group_NAME';
```